# How to write inline Ruby slim

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, slim-lang

I would like to have this H2 result in my view :

`Lot 1`

My views is write in slim and I use locales variables for `Lot`
How can I manage to put this both element (`Lot` and index) on the same line.

```
 - @products.each_with_index do |product, index|
        h1 = product.title
        h2 = t('product.lot') + (index + 1)
```

For the moment I have a synthax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
h2 = t('product.lot') + (index + 1).to_s
```

If think the issue is that you are making a concat between a string and a number

Wait, probably the best solution is interpolation because you need even a space

```
h2 = "#{t('product.lot')} #{index + 1}"
```